# How to remove trigger delay when calling ajax document?

Tags: javascript, ajax, delay

Ok.

Question is simple.

I want to call some document via ajax when user changed the value of `<input type="text">`.

Not even just 'keyboard typing' event.

Include that way... you know, the tool tip...which showing last input result of user...

I mean, that tool tip... position is below the input box... showing user's recent typed results... you know that.. hard to explain. don't know its name...

Anyway, I wanna call ajax document right after user changed value of `<input type="text">`... Not even just keyboard typing, include via choosing one of that tooltips by mouse clicking...

Well, I was able to call document right after 'key typing event'..

This is the code :

```
sensitiveInput.addEventListener('keyup',function(){
    callDocument_viaAjax();
}
```

So I tried similar method with above code.

This is the code :

```
document.addEventListener('mouseup',function(){
    if(sensitiveInput.value !== '') {
        sensitiveInput.onchange=function(){
            callDocument_viaAjax();
        }
    }
});
```

But this code had some delay.. That means, Failed to realize the ui that I want to make.

When user changed the value of `<input type="text" id="sensitiveInput">` via choosing one of the tooltips below input box, callDocument_viaAjax() wasn't executed.

I had to click on the document one more time to execute `callDocument_viaAjax()`....

I don't know why this happening.

And don't know how to solve this problem...

Please some one show me the mercy...

Comment: I believe the name of the 'tool-tip' you refer to may be "auto-complete". I'd also try responding to the `change` event in addition to the `keyup` event.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using an event trigger 'input'.
'input' event detect change of input even if do not lose the focus from input field.
('change' effects only when input field loses focus)